# Is there a hook/method etc. in NextJs that is equivalent to the createRef() hook in original ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, create-ref

I am trying to use 3rd party package `ReactPhotoSphereViewer` in NextJs to display panoramic images in the website.
The package works both in NextJs and in ReactJs.

Here is the code that is works in ReactJs:

```
import { ReactPhotoSphereViewer } from 'react-photo-sphere-viewer';
import React, {createRef, useEffect} from 'react';

...
function PanoramaImage({src}) {
  return (
    <ReactPhotoSphereViewer 
      src={src}
    ></ReactPhotoSphereViewer>
  );
} 
...
export default PanoramaImage;
```

Here is the code for same purpose in NextJs:

```
import React, {createRef, useEffect} from "react";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const ReactPhotoSphereViewer = dynamic(
  () =>
    import('react-photo-sphere-viewer').then(
      (mod) => mod.ReactPhotoSphereViewer
    ),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
)

...
function PanoramaImage({src}) {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactPhotoSphereViewer
            src={src}
        ></ReactPhotoSphereViewer>
      </div>
    )
}
...

export default PanoramaImage;
```

However when I tried to add reference to the `ReactPhotoSphereViewer` component, it works in ReactJs, but not in NextJs.

Here is the code after adding reference.

```
...
function PanoramaImage({src}) {
  const photoSphereRef = createRef(<ReactPhotoSphereViewer />);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!photoSphereRef.current)
      return;

    photoSphereRef.current.toggleAutorotate();
  }, [photoSphereRef]);

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactPhotoSphereViewer
            ref={photoSphereRef}
            src={src}
        ></ReactPhotoSphereViewer>
      </div>
    )
}
...

export default PanoramaImage;
```

I think the problem is createRef hook here. So, is there any method that I can use instead of createRef, or if I am using it wrong, how should it be correct.

I would be glad if you help. Thank you.

**edit: The problem is not on the createRef, I used useRef instead of createRef for both ReactJs and NextJs frameworks, ReactJs works perfectly, but I don't know why, NextJs does not detect the reference.
Finally I gave up using NextJs and start working with ReactJs.
Thank you for everybody.**

Comment: Why do you use `createRef` instead of `useRef`?

Comment: Why do you create two `ReactPhotoSphereViewer` components? One in `createRef` and another one in `return()`?

Comment: useRef: The useRef is a hook that uses the same ref throughout. Saves its value between re-renders in a functional component and doesn’t create a new instance of the ref for every re-render. It persists the existing ref between re-renders.

createRef: The createRef is a function that creates a new ref every time. Unlike the useRef, it does not save its value between re-renders, instead creates a new instance of the ref for every re-render. Thus implying - it does not persist the existing ref between re-renders. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-useref-and-createref-in-reactjs/

Comment: @Konrad I need the reference of the component to use some functions and the documentation suggesting using createRef, I am not a master of React/Next actually and I am looking for the correct way.

How should it be if I can get the same result using useRef?

documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-photo-sphere-viewer

Comment: I changed `createRef ` to `const photoSphereRef = useRef(null);`.
It worked for ReactJs but still does not work in NextJs.

Comment: Next it is the same React. Make simple representation of your code at codesandbox, i think problem somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Use useRef hook.
The difference is that createRef will create a new ref on render.
With functional components you need the same ref each time. useRef does it.

```
function PanoramaImage({src}) {
  const photoSphereRef = useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!photoSphereRef.current)
      return;

    photoSphereRef.current.toggleAutorotate();
  }, [photoSphereRef]);

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactPhotoSphereViewer
            ref={photoSphereRef}
            src={src}
        ></ReactPhotoSphereViewer>
      </div>
    )
}
...

export default PanoramaImage;
```

Comment: useRef is perfectly worked just like createRef in ReactJs, but I don't know why the same code does not work with NextJs. However, I gave up to fix it, instead, I started working with ReactJs. Thank you a lot.

Comment: our production projects in Next js, I work with next about 2 years. useRef works there absolutely similary to react

Answer (score 0):

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

// import { ReactPhotoSphereViewer } from 'react-photo-sphere-viewer';
const ReactPhotoSphereViewer = dynamic(
  () =>
    import('react-photo-sphere-viewer').then(
      (mod) => mod.ReactPhotoSphereViewer
    ),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

export default function Home() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactPhotoSphereViewer src="Test_Pano.jpg" height={'100vh'} width={"100%"}></ReactPhotoSphereViewer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Source: NPM

Or take a look at this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sandbox-react-photo-sphere-viewer-by-elius94-j064sm?file=/src/App.js

(Credit to original author elius94)